# Visual Studio: Displaying ALL project errors and warnings not just one project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

New to VS...  When I debug I get 10 errors and 20 warnings but the only options for seeing them is by Open Documents, Current Documents or Current Project.  As a result I can only find 4(4 of 10) of the errors on a specific project but can't find the remaining 6 errors.  Is there a way to just list them all rather than having to search for each project?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see *all* errors and warnings in the [Error list window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx). You can then navigate to the error or warning by clicking on it.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't see all errors.  I can only see 4 of the 10, not the other 6.  I WANT to see them all but it only shows me the current project errors not all of them.